# Why did they travel back in time with the Fourth Dark Curse?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon a Time*, when Regian casts the Fourth Dark Curse to save Henry they got traveled back in time too. But why? What was the point of that and why did it happen? Was it an accident or Gothal wanted it like that and what she gained form time travel?